# Flask jwt POST data to endpoint with a token

Tags: python, authentication, flask, python-requests, jwt

This Flask endpoint is what I am trying hit with Insomnia with a jwt token on a POST:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@token_required
def json_payloader():

    try:
        some code to do stuff...
```

Poking around the internet no matter what I try I always get back a:

```
{
  "message": "Token is missing!"
}
```

Bearer authentication token:
[image]

OR with authentication set to None and just trying headers with the token this also fails:

[image]

Any tips try greatly appreciated.

***EDIT*** `token_required` function

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import flask
from flask.helpers import make_response
import jwt
from functools import wraps

def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get('token')
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing!'}), 403
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        except:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is invalid'}), 403

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Comment: Could you please show where `token_required` is imported from?

Comment: I added in an EDIT to the post

Comment: It seems like the basic issue is that you're trying to retrieve the token from the args but it's in the headers: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a different version of flask-jwt (or flask-jwt-extended) then I believe the correct function decorator is `@jwt_required()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using JWTs. So, the correct decorator to be used is `@jwt_required`.
Please see the example from https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/#basic-usage .

```py
@app.route("/protected", methods=["GET"])
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    # Access the identity of the current user with get_jwt_identity
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_user), 200
```

If you want to create your own implementation, you can retrieve it like

```py
auth_header = request.headers.get("Bearer", "").strip().strip(",")
```